# Lenovo W520 + Ubuntu 14.04 --> external monitor not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have the W520 from Lenovo with Ubuntu 14.04, and would like to use it with an external monitor from Dell (U2515H). I connected the monitor through the display port with the laptop. I am using the nvidia-driver and I activated the "discrete" option in the bios ( I do not really care about optimus since I am using the laptop as a stationary workstation). In the "nvidia-settings" the monitor does get recognized and I can activate and deactivate the monitor. The issue is that the monitor always stays black?

Is there somebody who could help me with how to approach this issue. I also attached some screenshots of the nvidia-settings and the additional drivers menu.

[image]

[image]

FYI: I also posted this question in some other forum. I will mark it clearly as solved in all locations once it is solved! Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up dual monitors with nVidia?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84181/how-can-i-set-up-dual-monitors-with-nvidia) (The OP also has a W520)

Comment: Hi, THX. But this does  not help. I habe done everything that is suggested in that that thread and yet The external monitor remains black.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was eventually a problem with the cables. It is now fixed.